# How to fix the error of vscode Language Server without upgrading the OS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

`Language Server: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime`

How to fix the issue?
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2344

My Mac OS and version: OSX 10.10 and I don't wanna upgrade the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a virtual machine (VirtualBox (free), VMware, Parallels) or Docker and run your software within it. VM integration usually features folder sharing, so you can reuse your data.